# I change when to where - another riddle

Tags: riddle

I managed to write a rhyming one this time!

*I sound like a sieve, 

But knowledge I give. 

I change when to where; 

Just find the right square.*

*A cycle moves me to the right, 

But never entirely out of sight. 

Seven by four, or usually more, 

Betwixt the ceiling and the floor.*

What am I?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like it could be a

> Calendar

I sound like a sieve

> Maybe a sieve is a grid

But knowledge I give

> Calendar can be an external brain for keeping track of everything

I change when to where

> As an appointment time approaches, it will tell you where you need to be

A cycle moves me to the right
But never entirely out of sight

> A cycle of days is a month and as months increase, they normally show a smaller version of the prior and next month. As we imagine a year goes left to right, this may indicate direction.

Seven by four or usually more

> 28 days in Feb, otherwise 29, 30 or 31

Betwixt the ceiling and the floor

> Hangs on the wall.

From the comments on where I was a little off -

> A "sieve" is like a colander, which sounds like calendar. "When to
>   where" is supposed to mean that 'which day?' when you're looking on a
>   calendar becomes a spatial question rather than a temporal one. A
>   "cycle" is supposed to mean a day; as each day passes (unless it's the
>  end of the week) you move one square to the right on the calendar. – 
>  rand al'thor

Comment: The cycle part is not 100% convincing, otherwise nice one! I find especially clever the `seven by four` and the `when to where`.

Comment: Well done! This was the answer I was looking for. Not all the interpretations were quite what I intended though.

Comment: A "sieve" is like a colander, which sounds like calendar. "When to where" is supposed to mean that 'which day?' when you're looking on a calendar becomes a spatial question rather than a temporal one. A "cycle" is supposed to mean a day; as each day passes (unless it's the end of the week) you move one square to the right on the calendar.

Comment: @randal'thor colander, ah! Makes sense. I kept thinking "sifter".

Comment: Feel free to suggest improvements to the question; we were just talking about this over at the [Green Llama](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524/the-green-llama)!

Answer (score 4):

> The blackboard

I sound like a sieve,

> For the sound of the chalk

But knowledge I give.

> I'm used for teaching

I change when to where;
Just find the right square.

> The tool to wipe

A cycle moves me to the right, 
But never entirely out of sight.

> Less clear to me, but perhaps it refers to those that can be swapped

Seven by four, or usually more,

> Feet?

Betwixt the ceiling and the floor

> Usually hanging on the wall

Comment: This looks like the one. For me even `A cycle moves me to the right, But never entirely out of sight` makes sense with your answer.

Comment: @MohitJain my doubt comes from the fact that not all *** are of the scrolling type

Answer (score 0):

I think you are

> **A compass**

I sound like a sieve,

> used to distinguish directions (North, East, West, South).

But knowledge I give.

> give knowledge about locations and how to reach a place.

I change when to where;

> is used to find the answer for 'where?'. That is, to find locations.

Just find the right square.

> To decide in which direction the squire map is to be held in an exploration or journey.

A cycle moves me to the right,

> Circular rotation of the needle.

But never entirely out of sight.

> will always be kept in the pocket or hand

Comment: I don't follow your reasoning for 'sieve'. Also what about the last two lines?